# Angular 5 Reactive Forms : There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on angular 5 Reactive Forms :
I had this error :
*There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"* 
I saw in others forums that problem can be for many reasons : 
  misspelling in the HTML template , forgetting to import "FormsModule" or  "ReactiveFormsModule", ....

I checked my code but i didn't find the issue 
Can you Help me please !!!

***Console error :***

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" (" 
    [(ngModel)]="user.FirstName" 
    formControlName="FirstName"
    [ERROR ->]#FirstName="ngModel" />
    <label for="firstName">{{ 'FIRST_NAME' | translate:param}}</label>")
   : ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@12:15
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
//angular moudel
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  
....

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .....
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
     ...
    AppRoutingMoudel,
  ],
    ...
})
```

**LoginComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './../../../model/user';
import {FormBuilder,FormGroup,FormControl,Validators,NgForm} from  '@angular/forms'
        ....
 export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

     user : User;
     userLoginForm: FormGroup;

      constructor(private userLoginFormBuilder:FormBuilder) { 

        this.user = new User ("TestName", "Yagmi",
                                    "TestName@Yagmi.com", "esay", "esay");

        this.userLoginForm = this.userLoginFormBuilder.group({
                        FirstName: new FormControl (this.user.FirstName,
                                         [Validators.minLength(4),])
            });
         }
    }
```

**LoginComponent.Html**

```
<form class="col s12" [formGroup]="userLoginForm" (ngSubmit)="saveUserLogin()">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12 m6">

        <input id="firstName" 
               type="text" 
               class="validate"
               [(ngModel)]="user.FirstName" 
               formControlName="FirstName"
               #FirstName="ngModel" />

        <label for="firstName">{{ 'FIRST_NAME' | translate:param }}</label>
        <p class="data-error data-validation" *ngIf="FirstName.errors?.minlength">
          min length is 4 caracters.
        </p>
        <p class="data-error data-validation" *ngIf="FirstName?.touched">
          touched.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**user.ts**

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public FirstName: string,
        public LastName: string,
        public Email: string,
        public Passeword: string,
        public ConfirmPasseword: string
   )
}
```

Comment: Can you attach your User model definition?

Comment: Why would you want to use template driven and reactive forms together, I suggest you choose either.

Comment: can you please tell me  what I have to remove to use only reactive forms

Comment: Thank you Alex I understand where is my error now

Answer (score 1):

I find where is my error I used template driven and reactive forms together
this why i had error (after i read the comment of Alex )

the solution is just to remove all template driven from my Html template

```
<form class="col s12" [formGroup]="userLoginForm" (ngSubmit)="saveUserLogin()">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12 m6">

        <input id="firstName" 
            type="text" 
            class="validate"
           //[(ngModel)]="user.FirstName" ==> to remove template driven
          formControlName="FirstName" //==> to keep reactive forms
         // #FirstName="ngModel" ===> to remove template driven 
   />

            <label for="firstName">{{ 'FIRST_NAME' | translate:param }}</label>
            <p class="data-error data-validation" *ngIf="FirstName.errors?.minlength">
              min length is 4 caracters.
            </p>
            <p class="data-error data-validation" *ngIf="FirstName?.touched">
              touched.
            </p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

also im my 
**LoginComponent.ts**

```
import {FormBuilder,FormGroup,FormControl,Validators} from '@angular/forms'
```

==> remove import **NgForm** no need with reactive forms

Answer (score 0):

In the line 
`#FirstName="ngModel"`
The component referenced needs to have defined "exportAs" value.

For example

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[tooltip]',
 exportAs: 'tooltip'
})
```

`#FirstName="tooltip"`

https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26

Comment: Sorry I did t understand why i have to create directive and for what . I just  try to flow the example given in angular.io and they didn't created any directive

Comment: Can you send me the tutorial link? I can try to find what's the key difference with your code

Comment: Thank you Zelda7 i found where is my error, for the website I just try to flow the office documentation of Angular